# NetBeans issue when creating a DB entity class

Tags: java, netbeans, entity, eclipselink, derby

I seem to have run into a problem with NB. I was able to successfully (with a few initial problems which seems to be a bug in NB) create an Entity Class from Database. The objective is to embed the database from a location into the application. The steps and issues are explained below.

**Resources:** 
~ Database [TourismDB] with two tables: "Tourists", "Tours"
~ Packages: META-INF, toursapp
~ Files: persistence.xml, Toursists.java, Tours.java, ToursUI.java

**Steps:** 
1. Create package ✔ 
2. Create new Entity Class from Database ✔ 
3. If not created yet, create a connection to physical location of DB on PC ✔ 
4. Complete all steps successfully and the files are created by NB, viz. META-INF Package and the custom package for the DB entity classes ✔ 
5. One of the class files created for a table creates a field which is a Serializable, but will be changed to Boolean and an error connected to the original Serial change is also changed to Bool. ✔ 
6. Create JFrame Form, add jTable and bind it to Tours table. ✔ 
7. Change META-INF\Persistence.xml JDBC url to exclude real path to physical location; eg. `jdbc:derby:C:\Projects\ToursApp\TourismDB` -> `jdbc:derby:C:\Projects\ToursApp\TourismDB` ✔ 
8. persistence.xml creates new lines which must be deleted. (See Append. 1) ✔ 
9. Save everything before running JFrame. ✔ 
10. Run JFrame and NB connects to EclipseLink, then throws exception. (expected; refer to bug 1) ✔ 
11. Restart NB and run file. Everything compiles correctly. ✔

**Appendix:**
1. Persistence.xml 
*Before*
[image: Persistence as created by NB]

*Binding Elements to a JTable*
[image: Persistence after binding]

Change the JDBC URL to exclude physical location. See step 7.

*After changes, before running*
[image: Persistence after changing]

**Bugs:**
1. After completing steps 1 - 9, I build the app for the first time, and NB throws exception: 
`[EL Info]: 2014-02-15 14:40:08.29--ServerSession(25525711)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461`
`[EL Severe]: 2014-02-15 14:40:12.342--ServerSession(25525711)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException`
`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'TourismDB' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291, see the next exception for details.`
`Error Code: 40000`
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException`
`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'TourismDB' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@765291, see the next exception for details.` 
`Error Code: 40000`

When this happens, I restart NB and compile the JFrameForm again, and this time, everything works as expected.

Why does this happen and why must I restart NB to get everything to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If restarting NetBeans allows your application to successfully open the database, then what's probably happening is that a previous copy of your application is still running inside of NetBeans, and Derby only allows one application at a time to open the database if you are using the Derby EmbeddedDriver.

You can confirm this by examining the complete Exception: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

You could switch to using the ClientDriver, or you could ensure that you completely stop the previous copy of your application prior to running it again.